# Is it okay to ask a question that you do not agree with?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20859985/1022697) and I realized after posting it that I **disagree** with everything I posted — [see my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859985/is-it-a-good-idea-to-always-return-an-object-if-new-is-forgotten#comment31295240_20859985).

Should I post an answer stating that I disagree with the approach and why, or leave it as is (as if I completely **agree** with everything I wrote)?

Comment: Your question was opinion based about a particular coding style. There's no right answer. And in your comments you stated *"I **never** use this method. It would make my code quite confusing..."* Sounds to me like you already made up your mind before posting the question.

Comment: How can one disagree with a question?

Answer (score 3):

Always ask in good faith. Questions where it becomes obvious that someone's trying to coerce others into arguing against something they don't like are frustrating - *particularly* if you miss the cue and end up arguing *for* it.

Right now, your question reads as though you were using (or considering) a technique and looking for potential problems that might bite you later. But if your *real* problem is that you don't want to use the technique and feel pressured to do so anyway... Then the only acceptable answer will be one that feeds into your own prejudices.

These questions often end badly for everyone involved.

If you're honestly looking for situations where the technique you're considering is ill-advised for practical reasons, then the question is fine as it is. If you're looking to sanity-check the reasoning behind your architecture, you might want to just be up-front about that (you also might want to ask that on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)). And if someone on your team is pressuring you to do something you don't want to do, you might want to stop trying to trump him with SO answers gained via a false pretense and instead check out similar questions on [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: How can I rewrite the question so that the answers still make sense, but I am not _trying_ to coerce anyone any which way?

Comment: Again, that depends on what you're trying to accomplish. Do you actually care about giving this technique a fair shake, learning when to use it effectively and when to avoid it? Or are you just looking for confirmation that your fear of it causing confusing code are valid? Or... Is this an interpersonal problem wrapped in a thin veneer of programming relevance?

Comment: I am trying to learn when / where would be a good place to use it. As I read the comments I came to hate the method, no idea why, I liked the idea when I was writing the OP. So in conclusion I __would__ like to know when ( / where) would be a good place to use that format.

Comment: Then I think your question is fine (mostly - see my edit). Ignore answers in comments - folks answer in comments when they don't have the time or conviction to actually flesh out a proper answer and defend it.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can provide a post that you don't agree with at all.  If you think that the post is going to be unhelpful, then you're probably better off improving or deleting it.  If you think it will be helpful, despite the fact that you disagree with it, then by all means keep it around.

You could also strive to remove options and assertions put forward in the post (potentially; this isn't always possible) and give it a more neutral tone.  You may also be able to alter the opinions put forwards without changing the underlying question/answer (well, for an answer, changing what it puts forwards would actually be okay, so long as it still answers the question).

Comment: Should I post my own answer stating what I disagree with and why?

Comment: @qwertynl I don't see how that would be an answer to the question (in this particular case) so...no.  It would probably make more sense on, say, meta, where you might post a feature request or start a discussion and then, based on the responses or later realizations provide an answer advancing an opposite viewpoint.  I don't really see it happening so much on SO, as SO isn't really about opinions, but rather finding a solution to a technical problem.